# Se puede almacenar un operador(+,-,*,/) en una variable?

Tags: javascript

```js
let simbolo=+;
let simbolo="+";

function suma(a,b){ 
    console.log(simbolo); 
   }
```

estoy intentando crear una calculadora pero me surgió la duda de si se podía almacenar un operador en una variable para luego aplicarlo, cuando lo guardo como tal me bota error, pero si lo guardo como string si se guarda pero me sale como si fuera NaN. Hay algún modo de guardar un símbolo de esos en una variable?

El primer let me bota error, el segundo me aparece que es NaN.

Comment: Deberias agregar tu codigo

Answer (score 4):

No puedes guardar un operador en una variable, pero puedes:

1. Crear un diccionario y tener las operaciones como claves (como string)

```js
let operando1=2;
let operando2=3;
let operador="+";

const operaciones =
{
  "+": (a,b) => a+b,
  "-": (a,b) => a-b,
  "*": (a,b) => a*b,
  "/": (a,b) => a/b,
}

console.log(operaciones[operador](operando1,operando2));

console.log(operaciones["*"](operando1,operando2));
```

2. Puedes usar [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

```js
let operando1=2;
let operando2=3;
let operador="+";

let resultado = eval(operando1 + operador + operando2); //eval("2+3");
console.log(resultado);
```

3. Puedes usar `new Function`

```js
let operando1=2;
let operando2=3;
let operador="+";

function operar(op1,oper, op2)
{
  return (new Function("return " + op1 + oper + op2))();
}

console.log(operar(operando1,operador,operando2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Si lo puedes hacer **mientras** el valor de tu variable (el operador) sea cadena, así puedes concatenar el operador sin problemas:

```js
let simbolo = '+';
function suma(a, b) {
  return `la suma de ${a} ${simbolo} ${b} es ${a + b}`;
}
console.log(suma(1, 2));
```

Comment: Osea que no se puede almacenar como símbolo si no como string únicamente no?

Comment: Sip, eso mismo.

Comment: @JuanCaro no estás guardando ningún operador en tu primer intento. El intérprete del código no está viendo una asignación; va a intentar resolver la operación que le indicas y ahí sí, asignar el resultado a la variable. Como no hay operandos, encuentra el símbolo `;` y falla.